# join two column with same field of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one issue with mysql query to fetch name of sender and receiver from user table

i have below structure for `user_match_list` table

[image]

and this is `users` table

[image]

i want to join senderId with user table and get firstname + lastname as senderName
same as for receiverId and get name as receiverName
please guide me
thanks

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want two `join`s:

```
select uml.*,
       concat(us.firstname, ' ', us.lastname) as sendername,
       concat(ur.firstname, ' ', ur.lastname) as receivername,
from user_match_list uml join
     users us
     on uml.sendid = us.id join
     users ur
     on uml.receiverid = ur.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use two joins:

```
SELECT us.firstName + ' ' + us.LastName,
       us2.firstName + ' ' + us2.LastName
FROM dbo.user_match_list AS um
INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS us ON um.senderId = us.Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS us2 ON uml.receiverId = us2.Id
```